# Return JSON from MySQL with Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I use PHP to fetch a row from MySQL and then encode it into JSON using the following code

```
$jsonData = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
$json = json_encode($jsonData);
echo stripslashes($json);
}`
```

However, I only get the the row values. I want rows values along with their column names. Currently it returns the following JSON.

```
[["shekhar","Shekhar Chatterjee","https://graph.facebook.com/1254850974526564/picture","0"]],[["shek","Shekhar Chatterjee","","0"]]
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
[{
  "user":"shekhar",
  "name":"Shekhar Chatterjee",
  "url":"https://graph.facebook.com/1254850974526564/picture",
  "stat":"0"
 },{
  "user":"shekhar",
  "name":"Shekhar Chatterjee",
  "url":"https://graph.facebook.com/1254850974526564/picture",
  "stat":"0"
}]
```

Comment: Does it have to be in that format or can you first row just be an array of column names? If your first row is the column names, then you aren't repeating data and you still get the values.

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row`

Comment: The [PHP mysqli Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) When all else fails you could try reading that

Comment: @bassxzero bad idea. That would just push the requirement on the receiver of the json to maintain the association of a `fields` vector to each `value` of the results array. If you design APIs , make its use convenient, practical, and dont inject unsound principles/constructs in the semantics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Here you go

```
$jsonData = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
$json = json_encode($jsonData);
echo stripslashes($json);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`.

It should return the result with the respective fieldnames.

You can find the manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: I'm glad I could be some help there :3 Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) here instead so that it returns the key as the column names. mysqli_fetch_row returns numeric array keys instead.

Try this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $jsonData[] =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
$json = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, you don't need to perform an additional `addslashes()`, you can add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as the second argument of `json_encode()`.

```
echo json_encode($jsonData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question and would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: Agreed, however with mobile app limited comment capability I am unable to get correct formatting of code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just so if anyone else bumps in to this in year 2018, here is the complete example.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db_name");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$jsonData = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
$json = '{"my_data":';
$json .= json_encode($jsonData);
$json .= '}';
echo stripslashes($json);
}

?>
```

...