# how to get value of variable from webpage into Android TextView?

Tags: php, android

I would like to get a value of `Integer` from my PHP pages and insert to Android `TextView`
Example: I assigned "**int level = 1**" in PHP page and I want insert this value of variable "level" to Android `TextView`.

Anyone here can help me or give me a link of tutorial?

Appreciate for your kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue. RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL. StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    } }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    } }); // Add the requestto the RequestQueue. queue.add(stringRequest);
```

This code should represent your problem, it might be helpful. If it's not, take a look at the link. 
Source: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: In this code, how android get the value of variable "level"?

Comment: @user3208987 You can just echo it out in the php code... 
<?php echo level; ?> 
Whole output of the php website will be put into the TextView...

Comment: Oh, I got it, let me try. I will inform you the result soon.

Comment: @user3208987 ok, cool! I will be back on Stack Overflow in about 6 hours. D:

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, it's work fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can build or encode `Json` on that way you will also get that `KEY` and `VALUE` at Android side

**Like:** `{ key = values }`

where

`key = level(your TABLE column name)` and `value = 1`(your dynamic value)

If you want to know how to get `column_name` and encode `JSON` Follow [return JSON from mysql with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437306/return-json-from-mysql-with-column-name)

Comment: Do you mean I have to use Json like: php value to Json, and Json value to Android? can you please details more about this, because i am very new to json and android.

Comment: you can encode json with its column name that you have stored in to your data base and its value That's it